# Retrieving max value per category fails

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm attempting to retrieve the max unit price per category (Project) but it always returns the min value. Any help or feedback regarding how to return the max value is greatly appreciated.

Dax attempt:

```
Max of Unit Price max per Project = 
MAXX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Table1'[Project])),
    CALCULATE(MAX('Table1'[Unit Price]))
)
```

The data example below consists of a single category (column not shown). The max value should be 3.58 but is instead 1.79.

Data example and output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the max value per category,  you can use the below DAX,

```
Max of Unit Price = CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Sheet1'[Unit price]),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'sheet1', 'sheet1'[Category] ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

want to clear that the first answer is already work, hereby just add another formula for your reference.

if you want to use MAXX, try this one:

```
    Max of Unit Price = 
    MAXX(FILTER('Table1',[project]=EARLIER('Table1'[project])),
    [unit price])
```

[image]